# How to blit a transparent surface onto screen ie. for it to not be displayed

Tags: c, sdl

Hey I'm trying to find out which channel is alpha.
But everytime I blit what I think should be a completely transparent surface it turns out to modify the RGB channels as well.
SDL 1.2-master

Here's my code and what I've problem with:

```c
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO | SDL_INIT_TIMER) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't initialize SDL: %s.\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(-1);
    }

    SDL_Rect** modes = SDL_ListModes(NULL, SDL_FULLSCREEN|SDL_HWSURFACE);
    if(!modes) {
        printf(":(\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(modes[0]->w, modes[0]->h, 0, SDL_FULLSCREEN | SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
    if(!screen) {
        printf(":(\n");
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE|SDL_SRCALPHA, 32, 32, 32, 0xff000000, 0x00ff0000, 0x0000ff00, 0x000000ff);
    if(!surface) {
        printf(":((\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for(int i=0; i!=32; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j!=32; j++) {
            // 0 blue
            // 1 green
            // 2 red
            // 3 alpha?
            ((char*)(surface->pixels))[0+i*4*32+j*4] = 0xff;
            ((char*)(surface->pixels))[1+i*4*32+j*4] = 0xff;
            ((char*)(surface->pixels))[2+i*4*32+j*4] = 0xff;
((char*)(surface->pixels))[3+i*4*32+j*4] = 0xff; // SDL_OPAQUE_ALPHA is 0xFF

            // not an alpha channel
        }
    }
    int ret = SDL_BlitSurface(surface, NULL, screen, NULL);

SDL_Flip(screen);
sleep(2);

    for(int i=0; i!=32; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j!=32; j++) {
            // 0 blue
            // 1 green
            // 2 red
            // 3 alpha?
            ((char*)(surface->pixels))[0+i*4*32+j*4] = 0x30;
            ((char*)(surface->pixels))[1+i*4*32+j*4] = 0x40;
            ((char*)(surface->pixels))[2+i*4*32+j*4] = 0x50;
((char*)(surface->pixels))[3+i*4*32+j*4] = 0x00;// This surface should be transparent, SDL_TRANSPARENT_ALPHA is 0

            // not an alpha channel
        }
    }
    int ret = SDL_BlitSurface(surface, NULL, screen, NULL);
    
    while(1) {
        SDL_Flip(screen);
//if the color is anything but pure white, alpha channel modification failed.
    }
}
```

I basically need this code working for font handling.
For now I do one surface per glyph(Yeah I should do something else).
I need to be able to set the alpha channel to a value of the surface and have a guarantee that if the alpha is set to partial/full transparency that the RGB values of the texture don't get blitted.

Comment: Never do it myself, but there is a `SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode` function may help.

Comment: That function is available on 2.0+ onwards

Comment: So you are using SDL 1x?  A quick at the 1.x documentation, I noticed there is a `SDL_SetAlpha`.  I have no experience on version 1.x. You may need check it out yourself : https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlsetalpha.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this example:

```c
void main(void) {
    unsigned int t = 0x000000ff;
    unsigned char *ct = (unsigned char*)&t;
    printf("0x%x 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x\n", ct[0], ct[1], ct[2], ct[3]);
}
```

On little-endian machine (i.e. most machines nowadays) it will output `0xff 0x0 0x0 0x0`. You set alpha mask to `0x000000ff`, meaning when you access pixels your byte offset for alpha channel is 0 (i.e. in memory it is placed as A,B,G,R).

On a big-endian machine the output would be `0x0 0x0 0x0 0xff`, as byte order in integer is opposite (R,G,B,A in memory).

If you look at SDL 1.2 [documentation for SDL_CreateRGBSurface](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlcreatergbsurface.html) you may notice that example code checks for `SDL_BYTEORDER` and reverses masks upon surface creation to keep consistent byte order.

You already set `SDL_SRCALPHA` flag upon surface creation, so no `SDL_SetAlpha` is required; but when you set surface values you set alpha value to incorrect offset, as alpha is at offset 0 (**if** you're on little-endian machine).

Comment: Yup it was about endianness of the mask. Thanks.